# Copy process output few lines to a file

Tags: command-line, text-processing, pipe

I want to copy the xinput-calibrator output to the temp.txt file from my Qt application.

I am starting the QProcess from the Application

Using the command `xinput_calibrator | tee log.txt`, I am able to copy the complete text but I need to save only few lines of the output to the file

Below is the output of the `xinput_calibrator`

```
Warning: multiple calibratable devices found, calibrating last one (VirtualBox mouse integration)
use --device to select another one.
Calibrating EVDEV driver for "VirtualBox mouse integration" id=12
    current calibration values (from XInput): min_x=4, max_x=65512 and min_y=-52, max_y=65816

Doing dynamic recalibration:
    Setting new calibration data: 66, 65483, -125, 65584


--> Making the calibration permanent <--
  copy the snippet below into '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf'
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "calibration"
    MatchProduct    "VirtualBox mouse integration"
    Option  "Calibration"   "66 65483 -125 65584"
EndSection
```

Just I need copy last 5 lines to the temp.txt file

Comment: `xinput_calibrator | | tail -n 5 | tee log.txt`?

Comment: Thanq @skwllsp , I got the command - 'xinput_calibrator | tail -n 5 | tee log.tx'

Answer (score 2):

As @skwllsp mentioned your problem can be solved with `xinput_calibrator | tail -n 5 | tee log.txt`. However, may I ask why you're using `tee` to achieve this?

> The `tee` utility copies standard input to standard output, making a copy
>        in zero or more files.  The output is unbuffered.

The purpose of `tee` is to write output to files *and* keep the pipe going to next command.

If you just want to send your output to a file you can do so with `>` or `>>`.

```
xinput_calibrator | tail -n 5 > log.txt
```

This would create `log.txt` if it doesn't exist, or *truncate it to nothing* if it already exists, and write the output to the file.

```
xinput_calibrator | tail -n 5 >> log.txt
```

This would append to the file, so that previous data isn't removed.  (It will create the file if it doesn't exist.)

---

Further reading:

- [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/135943)